# Make random character letters and display them one by one in the java swing

Tags: java, swing

I tried to make random letters but only with three letters, and I want to display them one by one in the window I made when the "random" button was pressed, but when I pressed the random button, the loop didn't stop. and in the same way I tried with the CLI it gave me the results I expected. I've tried it many times but it doesn't work. Please help?

Below is the complete source code of my program:

```
package testGrafik;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestRandom extends JFrame {

public TestRandom() {
    setTitle("Test Game");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    Board board = new Board();
    getContentPane().add(board);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestRandom();
}

public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener, 
MouseMotionListener {
    int x;
    int y;
    public boolean isMouseMoving = false;
    public boolean isClicked = false;

    public char[] character = {'S', 'O', 'I'};
    public Random rand = new Random();

    public Board() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 500, 500);

        // draw box
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x + 10, y + 10, 70, 40);

        if (isMouseMoving == true) {
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(x + 10, y + 10, 70, 40);
        }

        //draw string
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("Click", x + 25, y + 35);

        if (isClicked == true) {
            char c = character[rand.nextInt(character.length)];
            String convertString = String.valueOf(c);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE); // border color
                g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30)); // 
    String.valueOf(hrf)
                g.drawString(convertString, x + 500 / 2, y + 500 / 2); // 
border boax t4 huruf muncul
                System.out.println("Latter: " + convertString); 
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();

            if (mx > x + 10 && mx < x + 10 + 70 && my > y + 10 && my < y + 
10 + 40) {
                isClicked = true;
                System.out.println("YOU CKLIK ON THE BOX");
            } else {
                isClicked = false;
                System.out.println("You click outside the box");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            int mx = e.getX();
            int my = e.getY();

            if (mx > x + 10 && mx < x + 10 + 70 && my > y + 10 && my < y + 
10 + 40) {
                isMouseMoving = true;
            } else {
                isMouseMoving = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the code that I tried with CLI:

```
package testGrafik;

import java.util.Random;

public class TestRandomCLI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] character = {'S', 'O', 'I'};
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        char c = character[rand.nextInt(character.length)];
        String convertString = String.valueOf(c);
        System.out.println("Latter: " + convertString);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you call `JComponent#repaint()` method inside `JComponent#paintComponent()`. When you call `repaint()`, `paintComponent` will be called. Then again, `repaint()` will be called...and you got the point.

**The solution:**

Call `repaint()` only 1 time, when the user clicks.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if (mx > x + 10 && mx < x + 10 + 70 && my > y + 10 && my < y + 10 + 40) {
        isClicked = true;
        System.out.println("YOU CKLIK ON THE BOX");
        repaint(); //Only 1 call after call
    } else {
        isClicked = false;
        System.out.println("You click outside the box");
    }
}
```

and of course remove it from `paintComponent()`

```
 if (isClicked == true) {
        char c = character[rand.nextInt(character.length)];
        String convertString = String.valueOf(c);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE); // border color
            g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30)); // 
            g.drawString(convertString, x + 500 / 2, y + 500 / 2); // 
            System.out.println("Latter: " + convertString); 
        }
        //repaint();
    }
```

Comment: @wenda, The painting method should never change the properties of the class. This means you should not be using the rand(...) method in the paintComponent() method. Instead you need a method like `generateRandomLetters()`, which would be invoked when you click a button. Then you set a property of your class to be the random String and the paintComponent() method will simply pant the String. Remove the repaint() method will prevent the component from automatically repainting itself, but you still can't control when Swing determines the component needs to be repainted.